# Count prime numbers from an array in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalscript, turbo-pascal

I have a problem in PAscal. I want to count prime numbers but no result : 
My code is:

```
Program arrayToFunction;
const
 size = 5;
type
  a = array [1..size] of integer;
var
 aNumbers:  a = (1, 7, 3, 4, 5);
 iCountNumbers: integer;
function countPrimeNumbers( var arr: a) : integer;
  var
   i :0..size;
   sum,j,count: integer;
  begin
  sum := 0;count:=0;
  for i := 0 to size do
  begin
      for j := 2 to arr[i] do
          begin
               if(arr[i] mod j = 0) then sum:=1;
          end;
      if(sum=0) then count:=count+1;

  end;
 countPrimeNumbers := count;
end;
begin
 iCountNumbers := countPrimeNumbers( aNumbers ) ;*)
  writeln( 'Numbers: ', iCountNumbers);
  readln;
end.
```

For this array I want to get 3 but I get 2...I don't understand where is my problem. Help me please

Comment: Main problem as i can see is that you does not reinitialize `sum` variable, so after `sum` value becomes to 1, it always will be 1. Add `sum := 0;` after `if(sum=0) then count:=count+1;`. But there are also some errors in your code. For example your array index starts from 1 but loop `for i := 0 to size do` starts from 0 so you will have error in `arr[i]` at the first iteration.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any pascal ( 34 years ) but either the index starts from zero or one.  And you use both. So I'd guess that's what the problem is

Comment: This would be a great time to learn to use the debugger. It's highly unlikely, BTW, that you're using Free Pascal, Pascal Script, and Turbo Pascal all at the same time, since they're nowhere near compatible with the code you've written. Only add tags that *actually apply* to your question - don't just randomly add those that seem to be similar. In this case, those would appear tobe only `pascal` and `freepascal` or `pascal` and `turbo-pascal` (but not all of them).

Answer (score 5):

You have `type a = array [1..size] of integer;`, but then you iterate over the array using `for i := 0 to size`. The subscript needs to match the declared range.

You set `sum := 0;` before entering that loop, but never set it back to zero again. Once you find a non-prime, you'll set `sum := 1;`, and there it will stay. You never detect a prime once you've detected a non-prime.

The two primes you found were whatever garbage is at `arr[0]`, and the 1 at `arr[1]`. Notice that **1** is not a prime, but your code will conclude it is. **7** is a prime, but your code will think it is not, because it will eventually notice that it's divisible by itself.

Comment: Can you edit my code please? I edited but doesn't work

Comment: Wait, you want me to write your program for you? Are you sure this isn't homework?

Comment: @Harea: No, no one here will *edit your program* for you. You've been given the information you need in order to solve the problem. It's now up to you to use it.